# Why is svchost.exe(netsvcs) taking so much RAM?

Tags: windows-7, memory, svchost

I have suffered myself from this problem, with svchost.exe (netsvcs) taking over 30 - 50% of my total memory. 
There have been several cases of the same issue happening with lots of people.
What exactly is the problem with this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurs because a handle leak occurs in the Winmgmt service after you install Windows Management Framework 3.0 on the computer.

Note The Winmgmt service is the Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) service within the Svchost.exe process that is running under the LocalSystem account.

To fix this, check this link : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2889748

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's taking so much RAM is that the remote desktop service of Windows tries to limit the data that needs to be sent over the network. It uses bitmap caching to not have to send each small change on the desktop (only the 'changing pixels' need to be sent).

Now, 30% - 50% of your RAM does seem way to high, even for this. How much RAM does the PC have. Does this happen immediately after a system restart. If it does, it's best to reinstall this service to see if this has resolved the issue.

If you aren't using remote desktop (and are not planning to use it anytime soon), I'd suggest to disable this service altogether.
Go to your services list in Windows, and disable Remote Desktop Services. This should disable the process. Remember to also stop the service, so it will stop immediately (not only after a system restart).